# IF ELSE syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My `IF..ELSE` block fails at `BEGIN`. I can understand how my expression is not boolean in nature, but what is causing this failure?

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@PARIDIN,1,1) = 'P' 
BEGIN
  SET @PARIDTEMP = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@PARIDIN)),2,6))
END
BEGIN
  ELSE SET @PARIDTEMP = @PARIDIN
END
```

Comment: ALL CAPS IS SOOO MUCH FUN! But you should **stop that** right now - it's really hard to read, really annoying - and it's considered **SHOUTING** at people which is rude and unwelcome. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra set of parentheses in a weird place.:

```
IF SUBSTRING(@PARIDIN,1,1) = 'P' -- one at the beginning of this line.
 BEGIN
  SET @PARIDTEMP = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@PARIDIN)),2,6) -- one at the end of this line.
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @PARIDTEMP = @PARIDIN
 END
```

Comment: Due to what @Sean Lange mentioned, I moved the `ELSE` outside of the `BEGIN` and `END` block.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the expression being evaluated.

Change

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@PARIDIN,1,1) = 'P'
```

To

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@PARIDIN,1,1) = 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking everybody else's suggestion of fixing the condition I am surprised nobody mentioned the very strange BEGIN END blocks. They don't make sense and not sure they would even work. Since you have only a single statement for each it makes more sense to remove them.

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@PARIDIN,1,1) = 'P')
  SET @PARIDTEMP = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@PARIDIN)),2,6))
ELSE 
    SET @PARIDTEMP = @PARIDIN
```

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` are not strange.  They are there for a reason.  They allow you to execute multiple statements inside of the `IF` or `ELSE` blocks.  IMO, it is better to have this construct before others modify the code, so we don't end up with unexpected results (thought and `ELSE` block would cause a syntax error without a valid `IF` block before it.  Though I do see the incorrectly placed `ELSE` as a problem.

Comment: I fully understand the point, I was stating the structure of the way the OP had them was quite strange. The else was inside the BEGIN. Sorry you misunderstood my comment I should have been more clear.

Comment: Thank you Sean, that was indeed very helpful